# Is it possible to disable certain weapons (ie: AWP)?

Tags: server-administration, counter-strike-global-offensive

I am in the process of configuring a Counterstrike: Global Offensive server and I was wondering if it was possible to disable certain weapons (for example, the AWP) or enforce certain weapons under particular conditions like it was in Counterstrike: Source*?

<sup>* (I do believe it required a mod for CS:S but I'm unsure on this)</sup>

Ideally I'd like to permanently disable AWP and enforce a knife round until each person has a kill (essentially making the first round knifes only) but I can't find a way to do this for Counterstrike: Global Offensive.

Is this possible at all?

Comment: It seems to be possible to directly disable the 'zeus' weapon via setting `mp_weapons_allow_zeus` to 0, but this appears to be the only weapons_allow variable... (there isn't, for example, a mp_weapons_allow_awp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to restrict certain weapons with the use of certain mods.

There is a mod out there that requires SDKHooks to use, but allows weapon disabling, including warm-up rounds.

Here's the mod: http://forums.alliedmods.net/showthread.php?p=950174